# Sql server : xml truncated while querying in php

Tags: php, sql-server, xml, truncated

While querying a xml data from SQL server database, it returns a truncated xml.

```php
$db = DB::get();

$db->exec('SET ANSI_NULLS ON');
$db->exec('SET ANSI_PADDING ON');
$db->exec('SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
$db->exec('SET ARITHABORT ON');
$db->exec('SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON');
$db->exec('SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF');
$db->exec('SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON');

$query = "select CAST(db.function(199) AS nvarchar(max))";
$result = $db->query($query);
$xml = $result->fetchColumn();
```

If the length of $xml is too big, it will be truncated. Is there a way to get the full xml whatever its size is ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I added these lines `before` the query :

```
$query = "select LEN(CAST(dbo.f_XML_Facture($IDFacture) AS nvarchar(max)))";
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    if (($length = $result->fetchColumn()) !== false) {
        $txt = "SET TEXTSIZE " . ($length*2);
        $db->exec($txt);
    }
}
```

The `SET TEXTSIZE (number)` allows us to define the length of xml we want to retrieve.

Comment: Most likely `$length*2` is not the correct way to determine the true length, it might work but you might have inherited a problem here. Just saying.